# Bunch of letters? It is all Greek to me

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, sequence

I found this paper on Grandpa's desk with a bunch of letters, big and bold, with a question:

Which two letters come next in the sequence?  He even wrote down four choices

[image]

[image]

Which two letters go next?

Curiously he had scribbled at the bottom:

" I don't think I can go any further in this sequence"

Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps Grandpa's sequence is based on

> $\sqrt{2} = 1.41421356 ...$

When writing l, M, l, M, X  consider the number of

> straight lines strokes: 1, 4, 1, 4, 2 then the next digits 1, 3 match the option **I, F**

I don't think I can go any further in this sequence as the next

> number is 5 and no (straight) letter has takes five: A, E, F, H, l, K, L, M, N, T, V, W, X, Y, Z

Title: Bunch of letters? It is all Greek to me

> Pythagoreans discovered that the square root of two is irrational, and a proof is in Euclid.

Comment: I absolutely did expect an answer from you @Tom. May be I should not have commented on the "Greek" being important.:)  Wonderful. BTW some people (Wikipidia) call this a Pythagoras Constant

Comment: rot13(Avpr zvfqverpgvba jvgu gur ebzna ahzrenyf, naq gur 'S' juvpu vf oernxf gur cnggrea.  Xvaq bs unq gb fvapr gurer'f ab guerr-fgebxr ebzna ahzreny, hayrff lbh pbhag 'Q', naq jebgr vg ebzna-fglyr nf n gevnatyr vafgrnq bs pheirq.)

Answer (score 2):

I think,

> XL

Explanation

> I think Grandpa is saying, "I'm I'm XXL".
>  *Big and bold*, *Can't go any further in this sequence* are probably mentioning about Grandpa's cloth size. I think it's not good for grandpa to put on more weight

Comment: His logic is very different, The title is important